# How to Print a Vaadin Flow dialog?

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a lot of dialog in vaadin flow which I want let user print them.
I know how to print the whole page as below code but I want only the dialog above the page be printed.

```
Button btnPrint = new Button( "Print…" );
    btnPrint .addClickListener( ( ClickEvent < Button > clickEvent ) ->
    {
         // this Prints the current page
        UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs( "print();" );
    } );
```

I did also tried this with java script but no success.

```
window.printPartOfPage = function (divPrintId) {
console.log("Inside printPartOfPage");
var printContent = document.getElementById(divPrintId);
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=100,top=100,width=600,height=600');
WinPrint.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
```

}

**Any Idea how to do it?**

Comment: How about making the Window full page size for the printing and resizing it afterwards?

Comment: What do you mean by full and resizing? Do you mean `dialog.setSizeFull();` and after print resizing it again?

Comment: Yes, something like that?

Comment: @aliakbarshahriariGaraei Haven't heard back on my answer. Did it work for you?

Comment: @Oliver It doesn't work yet, there is problem with scrolbar.

Comment: @aliakbarshahriariGaraei What is the problem with the scrollbar?

Comment: @Oliver It just shows the visibale part of dialog.

Comment: I didn't quite grasp what you mean with that. Could you edit the question to add a screenshot of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Both `vaadin-dialog` and `vaadin-dialog-overlay` are custom elements and use Shadow DOM. One of the main features of a Shadow DOM is to *mask* the initial DOM (called "Light DOM") with a new DOM (called "Shadow DOM"). Therefore, without some sort of web reflection, a call to `innerHTML` is not returning what you expected. Also, if it did work, you would have used `outerHTML`.

One solution is to use CSS...

Define a new style:

```css
.no-print {
  display: none !important;
}
```

And when you want to print, add that class to all elements except `vaadin-dialog` and `vaadin-dialog-overlay`:

```java
UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("" +
    "const body = document.body;" +
    "" +
    "for(let child = body.firstChild; child !== null; child = child.nextSibling) {" +
    "  if(child.tagName !== 'vaadin-dialog' && child.id !== 'overlay') {" +
    "    child.classList.add('no-print');" +
    "  }" +
    "  " +
    "}" +
    "" +
    "window.print();" +
    "" +
    "for(let child = body.firstChild; child !== null; child = child.nextSibling) {" +
    "  child.classList.remove('no-print');" +
    "}"
);
```

Obviously, this is not the most efficient method. Particularly because other elements, such as `script`s, will get the `no-print` class. But hopefully this gives you an idea.

I hope this helped!

Comment: Hi, did this answer your question?